# This code doesn't work. I mean when I press "submit" or "reset" button, nothing changes

Tags: html

```
    <fieldset style="padding: 20px;">
        <legend>Send Us A Message</legend>

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="David" required autofocus><br><br>
    </fieldset>
         <button type="submit">Send</button>
         <button type="reset">reset</button>
```

I have changed  to  but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Please use `<form>` or add js code

```
<form>
<fieldset style="padding: 20px;">
        <legend>Send Us A Message</legend>

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="David" required autofocus><br><br>
    </fieldset>
         <button type="submit">Send</button>
         <button type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

or add js code

Please let me know if this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 use form tag  <form> </form> 

<form> 
    <fieldset style="padding: 20px;">
        <legend>Send Us A Message</legend>

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="David" required autofocus><br><br>
    </fieldset>
         <button type="submit">Send</button>
         <button type="reset">reset</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in above answer, you need to use 
But also you need to specify action and method

```
<form method="POST" action="registration.php">
```